# Run animate before image shows

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I have a lightbox I have put together that will fade in an image into the other when next/previous is clicked.

What I am having trouble with, is animating the width and height of the lightbox BEFORE the image appears.

```
$('img#image').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500)

$('img#image').attr('src', image).load(function () {

    var imgWidth = $('img#image').width();
    var imgHeight = $('img#image').height();

    $('#lightbox').animate({ 'width': imgWidth + 20 }, 500).delay(1000);
    $('#lightbox').animate({ 'height': imgHeight + 100 }, 500).delay(1000);
    $('#lightbox img#image').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);

});
```

At the top I am animating the current image so it fadesout, then replacing it with the new image. I am then loading a function that gets the height and width of the image and animates the height and width of the lightbox so its bigger than the actual image.

Any help would be massively helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hide the image first then resize then show :

```
$('img#image').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500)

$('img#image').hide();  // ADDED THIS LINE

$('img#image').attr('src', image).load(function () {

    var imgWidth = $('img#image').width();
    var imgHeight = $('img#image').height();

    $('#lightbox').animate({ 'width': imgWidth + 20 }, 500).delay(1000);
    $('#lightbox').animate({ 'height': imgHeight + 100 }, 500).delay(1000);

    $('img#image').show();  // ADDED THIS LINE

    $('#lightbox img#image').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);

});
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I have tried this already and the image is still appearing before the width and the height of the lightbox has changed. It seems that the image appears when $('img#image').attr('src', image) is run, then it disappears when I hide it then animates back in when the animation occurs. Very Annoying. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: I think this http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ does exactly what you are trying to achive - have a look at the source and see how they do it ...